# Fatal Error when converting RGB to gray opencv

Tags: opencv

I am new to opencv i m trying to convert rgb video to grayscale but it always give error  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvCvtColor referenced in function _wmain
Please tell me what i am doing wrong

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "video.avi" );
    if(!capture)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage *bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);//Init the video read
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty (capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    CvSize size = cvSize((int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("izlaz.avi",CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT,fps,size);

    IplImage *grayScaleImage = cvCreateImage(size ,IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

    while( (bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture)) != NULL )
    {
        cvCvtColor(bgr_frame, grayScaleImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvWriteFrame( writer, grayScaleImage );
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
}
```

Comment: should that be a c or c++ program

Comment: it doesn't look like that

Comment: you're including C and c++ headers and your code is definitely in C

Comment: IplImage is for C not c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Library imgproc. I am using opencv 2.3. For this press

ALT+F7
configuration properties -> Input ->Additional dependencies -> Edit 
and copy this opencv_imgproc230.lib

Answer (score 0):

try this **UPDATE**

#include

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main (){

cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap("Grabbed video.avi");//("Wildlife.wmv");
int key =0;
cap>>frame;
cv::VideoWriter record("Grabbed2 video.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30,frame.size(), 0);
while(key != 27){
    if(cap.isOpened()){
    cap >>frame;
    if(!frame.empty()){
        cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        record<<frame;
        imshow("fvakjb",frame);
    }
    }

    else key =27;
    //cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);




key= cv::waitKey(10);
}
record.release();
cap.release();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::cvtColor(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int,int)" (?cvtColor@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@HH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>C:\Users\Ayesha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\newproject\Debug\newproject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: All other functions like  reading and writing videos are working correctly. and this code gives no error if i comment //cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);

Comment: make sure that you properly added the imagproc library in your project

Comment: can you please explain where i have to add this library I am very new to opencv

Comment: well the same way you added you're core.dll and highgui.dll , I have a question are sure that the video is in the folder of you project ?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder i had read and displayed that video in the same project

Comment: opencv_core230.lib
opencv_highgui230.lib I have added these 2 libraries and now tried to add opencv_imagproc230.lib but it gives error cannot open input file 'opencv_imagproc230.lib'

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using ?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 and my system is 64 bits

Comment: please update the code you're using so we can check if the problem is the code or the configuration of opencv on VS2010

Comment: your code is wrong you don'T need .h files only hpp try the the new code that I putted

Comment: I have tried its not working again giving same error and on commenting // cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY); works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Additionally ,

If you are using cmake and qibuild you can try this for linking :

It automatically links with the corresponding libraries and make their headers available.

```
qi_use_lib(yourProgramName your libraries)
```

like this:

```
qi_use_lib(getimages ALCOMMON ALPROXIES ALVISION OPENCV2_CORE OPENCV2_HIGHGUI OPENCV2_IMGPROC)
```